# UItabbarcontroller working on simulator but not on archive project

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I was working on one project and i finished everything in that project. Everything was working fine on simulator. But when i tried to archive the project to make it available through testflight to internal testers.

But when i tried to archive the project, i am facing problem with UITabBarController. On simulator application is working perfect but when i try to archive project or build for Generic IOS Device i am facing this issue.
Please help me in this issue. Screenshot is shown below

[image: Screenshot is attached]

Comment: What do the errors say? Also could be a good idea to clear DerivedData and clean the project (Ctrl + Shift + K)

Comment: Use of undeclared type 'UITabBarController'...If i run this app on iphone 7 in simulator then there is no error.
Using xcworkspace  Xcode 8. I just clear derive data and clean project but still same error.

Comment: If i delete the reference of the file then its working perfectly.... I have that file to do customization in Tab Bar... Like changing background color.. But its behaving like TabBar controller is not allowed to access from code side.

Comment: Solved...I update my xcode from 8 to xcode 9 and it started working. Apple technical code support wasn't able to help me.

Comment: i am using xcode 9.2 and having the same problem

Comment: I faced this issue when it was 8.3.2, but when i upgraded my project to xcode 9.2 it started working properly.
Try to change settings of your project target version to 11